# Unable to load favicon.ico for rest api in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, hapi.js

I have created a REST api using `hapi`, everything working fine locally. I tried to deploy it in `heroku`, application is crashing everytime and when i checked console for errors it shows:

> Failed to load resource: the server favicon.ico responded with a
>   status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

I checked how to handle this issue, I found few posts saying i need to add one endpoint to return a status code of 204 for `/favicon.ico`. I
 created a route for it as follows:

```
server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/favicon.ico',
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            return reply(require('fs').createReadStream('../../favicon.ico')).code(200).type('image/x-icon');;
        }
})
```

Again it works fine locally but in heroku i am getting same 503 error. the heroku logs reads like this:

```
2018-02-25T04:56:18.826225+00:00 app[web.1]: Server running at: http://localhost:16689
2018-02-25T04:57:16.324815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-02-25T04:57:16.324815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-02-25T04:57:16.406578+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
status 137
2018-02-25T04:57:16.418790+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-02-25T06:57:16.527520+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=profileapi.herokuapp.com
request_id=16403e1b-9e90-42f0-94c9-801960806944 fwd="157.49.157.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-25T06:57:17.983629+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=profileapi.herokuapp.com request_id=67f40452-1a05-440f-962a-a045563a73af fwd="157.49.157.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-25T06:57:27.478816+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=profileapi.herokuapp.com request_id=df2d9323-aa9d-4cff-9ef8-3722efda8a2f fwd="157.49.157.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-25T06:57:28.922698+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=profileapi.herokuapp.com request_id=cc5088e6-fb7b-4c7b-8bcb-c2db8556dd8e fwd="157.49.157.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I checked [hapi-favicon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-favicon), the module user guide documentation is empty. i checked the ways its using for `/favicon.ico` endpoint, i followed it still getting same error.

Can anyone have any suggestion/way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the `host` address provided while creating server, I was adding `HOST` and `PORT` to server connection as follows:

```
server.connection({
    host: (process.env.HOST || 'localhost'),
    port: (process.env.PORT || 1643)
});
```

Heroku dynamically assigns app to a port and host address. we have to use `(process.env.PORT || your_port)`. similarly it will assigns a host address dynamically. I removed host from connection. The final connection which resolved the issue is as follows:

```
server.connection({
    port: (process.env.PORT || 1643)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I set "engines":{
"node":"10.4.1",
"npm":"6.4.2"
}